# Computing sum by group on sparse array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse array like the following:

```
import scipy
my_sparse_array = scipy.sparse.random(2000, 1000000, density=0.01, format='csr')
```

And for each row, I have a group:
    groups = ["A", "A", "B", "C", "D"] * 400

Based on these groups, I want to get a sum of each column, and output an array with the rows now being the total group sum, and each column staying the same.

How can this be efficiently done with a sparse matrix?

Thanks,
Jack

EDIT:

One way of doing this might be to do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

results = {}
group_set = set(groups)
for group in group_set:
    indices = np.where(np.array(groups) == group)[0]
    results[group] = my_sparse_array[indices, :].sum(axis=0).A1

final_result = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

However, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way other than looping through groups and subsetting.

Comment: I don't quite follow. but you can readily do `my_sparse_array[:, 0::5].sum(axis=0)` etc.  Since indexing like this, and sum are both implemented as matrix multiplications, it might be possible to construct a suitable matrix such that `my_sparse_array * M` produces the desired result (at least for one group at a time).  However you do it I think you'll have to iterate through the groups to get to the full set.

Comment: Show us how you'd do this grouping for a small matrix (and group).  It could be dense if that's easier.  And for a start don't worry about efficiency.  We need a clearly define task first.

Comment: @hpaulj Hi, Thanks for the comment. I updated the question with a solution that is probably sub-optimal, if you could help improve this it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A few iterations, e.g. 5, with a complex task like indexing and summing a large sparse matrix, isn't inefficient.  What we try to avoid in `numpy` is many iterations on a simple task.